# How to handle bad or duplicate records in Statement.ExecuteBatch()

Tags: java, prepared-statement, ojdbc, batch-insert

I have a java program which processes a file of 1 Million records and insert it into a table using bulk insertion i.e. `Statement.addbatch()` and then `Statement.executeBatch()` after every 1000 records. The program runs quite fast.

However, if there is a duplicate record i.e. the table raises an exception the whole batch is gone and the rest of the records are un-trackable.

Even if I get the `updatecount()` is is of no help because I cannot insert the duplicates into another table etc.

Is there a way, that in 1 particular batch insert of 1000, if there is a bad record, then each record in that batch can be processed 1 by 1 so that the bad/duplicate records can be placed in another table and the non-duplicates in regular table ?

Is there any other class I can use ? I know in c++ the Oracle provides OCI which can handle single records in the batch (called Host array operation), but in Java the Bulk insertion is usually done by `Statement.adding` in the loop and then inserting it using `Statement.executeBatch()`.

Thanks.

Comment: you could collect those 1000 values in some container alongside the batch and if the batch fails run them one by one youself, no? if the batch succeeds clear the container and on to the next 1000

Answer (score 0):

I would break it up into smaller chunks of 1,000, like this

```
  final int BATCH_SIZE = 1000;
  for (int i = 0; i < DATA_SIZE; i++) {
   statement.setString(1, "a@a.com");
   statement.setLong(2, 1);
   statement.addBatch();
   if (i % BATCH_SIZE == BATCH_SIZE - 1)
   statement.executeBatch();
  }
  if (DATA_SIZE % BATCH_SIZE != 0)
  statement.executeBatch();
```

It is quite frequent for a batch of records to contain few bad ones. If you try to insert all the records in one go, and one record fails, the whole lot of insertions will be rejected. That is expected and is the core purpose of "transaction handling".

Usually for batch inserts, you can take two approaches:

1)Commit after each record insertion --> Very performance intensive process.

2)Divide the total records into smaller "chunks" and insert into database. So that just the chunk containing the bad record will fail and other chunks will be inserted into the database.

Alternatively, if you dont want to handle these things yourself, go for a framework. [Spring batch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/)

Could be one of your options in that case

Comment: You are executing the batch after each insert correct? Then what is the purpose of all this ? Secondly, if I have small chunks and then if one record fails, then I will still loose SOME of the records. The requirement is that no record should be lost. Every record must either go to table, OR a secondary table for duplicate records.